# Cannot see file in "Documents" directory even they are there(ANDROID API31)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I tried to access json files cread by application and saved in Documents folder. But event files are there I can't see them. I don't know what could be the reason, either I don't have permission to them or maybe directory path is wrong. I included only intent which open directory folder where user can choose file. On photos is diretory with files open manually(first photo) and from app using this intent.

[image]
[image]

```
  public static final String BACKUP_PATH = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) +"/Kalendarz zmianowy/Kopia zapasowa/";

 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileChooserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserActivity.PATH, ShiftCalendarApplication.BACKUP_PATH);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ShiftCalendarApplication.REQUEST_CODE_BACKUP);
```

Comment: `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")` Remove that line. It makes no sense for ACTION_PICK.

Comment: Thanks, I updated code, if you can please have a look. Action pick actually only let me open photos not documents folder.

Comment: I see no updated code for ACTION_PICK. It is pretty unclear what you do and where you are complaining about.